# How to upload Iform File in iframe ( was binding null) (javascript/jquery)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, iframe, asp.net-core-mvc

In asp.net core , i define `ProductUpdateRequest` has  `public IFormFile ThumbnailImage { get; set; }` . I create update form in iframe. when I submit form with

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#btnsubmit").click(function (e) {
        
        //Serialize the form datas.   
        var valdata = $("#updateProductForm").serialize();
        
        //to get alert popup   
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Products/Update",
            data: valdata,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(1);
            }
        });
    });   
    
});
```

asp.net have bind data from the form to request model :

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromForm] ProductUpdateRequest request)
```

but request.ThumbnailImage is null.
How can I post img (Iform File) to the server by ajax from iframe?
When update action is done, what would I do if I want to get a response to

```
success: function (response) {
                alert(1);
            }
```

and told to parent page to reload to update new data?
Help me, I can't understand this problem...

Comment: Hi @Thắng Nguyễn Quyết, Please share your html code.

Answer (score -1):

I work with asp mvc, not core.

`public IFormFile ThumbnailImage {get; set; }` **change to :**

```
public HttpPostedFileBase ThumbnailImage {get; set; }
```

in your view change form to this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)" }))
{
   
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="ThumbnailImage" type="file" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
}
```

and script change to this code:

```
function SubmitForm(form) {
      var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
        $.ajax({
          url: form.action,
          type: form.method,
          data: formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,

          success: function (response) {
             alert(response);
          }
     });
     return false;
}
```

and in controller change your action to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Update(ProductUpdateRequest model)
{
    //update db
    return Json("success");
}
```

Comment: ASP MVC and ASP Core MVC are too different.

Comment: There are differences, but what is the difference between using jQuery above, for example?

Comment: Your `Update` method is all wrong. 1) Almost always use ValueTask. 2) should be IActionResult not JsonResult in the return value. And the other C# fragments are worse off.